# Parse.com Receiving push notifications even if not subscribed to channel

Tags: android, json, rest, parse-platform, push-notification

i'm receiving push notifications even from channels i'm not subscribed to.

My app gets the user interest from a remote JSON and subscribe him to the channels in Parse.

I'll try to copy all the related code.

MyApplication.java

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
Parse.initialize(this, ParseAppID, ParseClientKey);
ParseInstallation installation=ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
installation.put("UniqueId", android_id);
installation.saveInBackground();
```

MainActivity.java (inside an AsyncTask onPostExecute)

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);

int error = jObject.getInt("Error");

ArrayList<String> channels = new ArrayList<String>();

if(error==0){
    JSONArray intereses = jObject.getJSONArray("Interests");

    Log.d("ChannelsTrack", "Error: 0");

    for(int j=0; j < intereses.length(); j++) {

        int interes = intereses.getInt(j);

        String channel_name="sdc_channel_" + interes;

        channels.add(channel_name);

        Log.d("ChannelsTrack", channel_name);

        ParsePush.subscribeInBackground( channel_name );
    }

    List<String> subscribedChannels = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getList("channels");
    for(int j=0; j < subscribedChannels.size(); j++) {

        if(!channels.contains(subscribedChannels.get(j))){
            ParsePush.unsubscribeInBackground( subscribedChannels.get(j) );
        }

    }

}else{
    Log.d("ChannelsTrack", "Error: " + error);
}
```

This is aparently working. I can see my Parse user subscribed to the specified channels y the console

I can't post images but, in Parse Core table it's a single row with ["sdc_channel_6","sdc_channel_5","sdc_channel_2","sdc_channel_3","sdc_channel_4"] in the "channels" column and it changes when i update the user interests so i think everything it's working at this point.

I'm using the REST API to send push notifications using this JSON

```
{
    "data": { 
        "action": "my.application.UPDATE_STATUS", 
        "t": "Text",
        "d": "Text 2", 
        "f": "",  
        "u": "http://example.com" 
    },
    "where": { 
        "channels": { 
            "$in": ["sdc_channel_99","sdc_channel_88"] 
        },
        "deviceType": "android" 
    }
}
```

And here is the problem. I receive the push notification sent to "sdc_channel_99" and "sdc_channel_88" channels but i'm not subscribed to them (and i've never been subscribed to them).

Obviously i'm missing something, any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in your compound query :

```
"where": { 
    "channels": { 
        "$in": ["sdc_channel_99","sdc_channel_88"] 
    },
```

"$in" means "Contained In" so if the user is subscribed to channel "sdc_channel_9" and channel "sdc_channel_8", the user will be selected.
may be you should try this query :

```
"where" : {"$or":[{"channels":"sdc_channel_99"},{"channels":"sdc_channel_88"}]}
```